# 2 standard 52 card decks, how many sequences with exactely 12 adjacent pairs of identical cards?

Tags: combinatorics

I am doing recreational math as a pastime. I like to do math exams and such and also to come up with math-puzzles on my own.

Recently i was doing the following MIT math exam:

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/exams/MIT6_042JF10_final_2004.pdf

It was super fun! :-)

Anyway, here is problem 7:

[image: picture of problem 7 of the exam]

That problem got me thinking about the problem I described below.

---

Take 2 standard 52 card decks.

Then you can take those cards and form sequences.

There are a total of $104! / 2^{52}$ possible different sequences.

From all of those only $52!$ exist that have $52$ pairs of identical cards placed right next to one another. For example ( Ad,Ad,Ah,Ah,As,As,...)

How many sequences are there with exactly 12 pairs?

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Your question is being closed because users do not like answering questions that contain just a problem statement. They would like to see some effort on the part of the asker, or information about the context in which you saw the problem, method you are familiar with, information about your mathematical experience so we can give an answer relevant to your knowledge, etc.

Comment: Per the comment of @MikeEarnest, one way of influencing mathSE reviewers to react positively, rather than negatively, to your question, is by consulting [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: For what it's worth, there are generally three methods that I know of for attacking such a question: [1] [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) [2] the direct approach, or [3] recursion.  For this particular problem, I suspect that each of the three plausible approaches will be challenging.

Comment: A fourth **sanity-checking** approach:  suppose that instead of $52$ cards in the deck, there are only $n$ cards.  Further suppose that instead of exactly $12$ pairs, you specify that there are exactly $k$ pairs.  Then, for $n \leq 16, k \leq 6$, you can write a computer program (i.e. in Java, C, Python, ...) to manually enumerate the satisfying sequences.  Then, you could study the results, and use this as an  **analytical guide** in your attack on the problem.  Note that $(n,k) = (52,12)$ is probably far too large to succumb to a home pc, in a reasonable time frame.

Comment: By the way, if you (for example) use numbers, rather than playing card designations, then, the following attempted shortcut is **invalid**:  the presumption, that without loss of generality, the cards in the odd positions (i.e. positions $1,3,5,\cdots,103$) are specifically $(1,2,3,\cdots,52),$ in that order.  This is an invalid presumption, because (for example) the first *card* could be the #1, while the two occurrences of #2 might both occur in an *even position*.  For example, a 104 number sequence that begins $1,3,3,2,4,2,\cdots.$

Comment: Not that it will be that helpful, but a preliminary research step might be to study [this derangements article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: There are $\binom{52}{12}$ way to pick the pairs. Remove one card from each pair. Then count the orderings of the remaining cards with no pairs together. This count will use inclusion-exclusion. In each case, you can re-insert the removed cards next to their corresponding twin and get an arrangement of all $104$ cards with exactly $12$ pairs together.

Comment: Using that argument, I get: $$\binom{52}{12}\sum_{k=0}^{40} (-1)^k\binom{40}{k}\frac{(92-k)!}{2^{40-k}}$$ but I’m not sure. I don’t see a way to get a simpler answer.

Comment: Although it seams to me like a perfectly harmless question, it is still closed. :-( Having said that, I want to thank everyone for their kind replies and excellent help! I think that especially the answer by Thomas Andrews is superb! Thank you so much! I really do appreciate everybody helping me out!

Comment: It was closed correctly because it lacked context. After you edited to include context, it was opened (correctly).

Comment: makes sense. cool :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we use *[PIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)*
, the principle of inclusion-exclusion as proposed by @ThomasAndrews. We then look at a small example which is intended as plausibility check and we provide an algebraic derivation.

**The problem:** We look at the more general case, consider $n$ pairwise different cards instead of $52$ and take two decks of them. We already know according to OP, the number of different sequences is
\begin{align*}
\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
since we can take all permutations of length $2n$ and identify $n$ pairs of the same type. We are looking for  the number of sequences which contain *exactly* $q$ pairs of the same type placed right next to one another, i.e. which form a run of length $2$.

**PIE:** We have $\binom{n}{q}$ ways to choose $q$ pairwise different cards which form the runs of length $2$. We take these $q$ cards from the deck and have now $2n-q$ cards from which we can make
\begin{align*}
\frac{(2n-q)!}{2^{n-q}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
different sequences. In (2) we have $n-q$ pairs left which justifies the denominator $2^{n-q}$. Note, the so derived number
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{q}\frac{(2n-q)!}{2^{n-q}}
\end{align*}
does not give the number of sequences with *exactly* $q$ pairs having runs of length $2$ but the number of sequences with *at least* $q$ pairs with runs of length $2$ instead. The number of sequences counted in (2) does also count sequences with runs of length $2$ of other than the selected $q$ pairs.

This is when PIE comes into play, since it enables us to transform *at least* information into *exact* information. Subtracting the number of sequences which contain *at least* $q+1$ pairs and adding the number which contain *at least* $q+2$ pairs, etc. gives the necessary compensation of over- and undercounting to finally derive the number of sequences with *exakt* $q$ pairs with runs of length $2$. The so derived formula is
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\binom{n}{q}\sum_{k=0}^{n-q}(-1)^k\binom{n-q}{k}\frac{(2n-q-k)!}{2^{n-q-k}}\qquad\qquad 0\leq q\leq n}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

**Small example: $n=3, q=1$** We calculate as plausibility check of (3) a small example. We consider three differenct types of cards $a,b,c$ and look- for the number of valid sequences of length $6$ which have exactly one pair with a run of length $2$.

> We obtain from (3)
> \begin{align*}
> \binom{3}{1}&\sum_{k=0}^{2}(-1)^k\binom{2}{k}\frac{(5-k)!}{2^{2-k}}\\
> &=\binom{3}{1}\left(\binom{2}{0}\frac{5!}{2^2}-\binom{2}{1}\frac{4!}{2^1}
> +\binom{2}{2}\frac{3!}{2^0}\right)\\
> &=3\left(30-24+6\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=36}
> \end{align*}
> The valid $\color{blue}{36}$ sequences having *exactly* one pair with run of length $2$ are
> \begin{align*}
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
> \mathrm{\color{blue}{aa}bcbc}&\mathrm{\color{blue}{aa}cbcb}&\mathrm{b\color{blue}{aa}cbc}&\mathrm{bc\color{blue}{aa}bc}&\mathrm{bc\color{blue}{aa}cb}&\mathrm{bcb\color{blue}{aa}c}\\
> \mathrm{bcbc\color{blue}{aa}}&\mathrm{c\color{blue}{aa}bcb}&\mathrm{cb\color{blue}{aa}bc}&\mathrm{cb\color{blue}{aa}cb}&\mathrm{cbc\color{blue}{aa}b}&\mathrm{cbcb\color{blue}{aa}}\\
> \mathrm{a\color{blue}{bb}cac}&\mathrm{aca\color{blue}{bb}c}&\mathrm{acac\color{blue}{bb}}&\mathrm{ac\color{blue}{bb}ac}&\mathrm{ac\color{blue}{bb}ca}&\mathrm{\color{blue}{bb}acac}\\
> \mathrm{\color{blue}{bb}caca}&\mathrm{ca\color{blue}{bb}ac}&\mathrm{ca\color{blue}{bb}ca}&\mathrm{caca\color{blue}{bb}}&\mathrm{cac\color{blue}{bb}a}&\mathrm{c\color{blue}{bb}aca}\\
> \mathrm{abab\color{blue}{cc}}&\mathrm{aba\color{blue}{cc}b}&\mathrm{ab\color{blue}{cc}ab}&\mathrm{ab\color{blue}{cc}ba}&\mathrm{a\color{blue}{cc}bab}&\mathrm{baba\color{blue}{cc}}\\
> \mathrm{bab\color{blue}{cc}a}&\mathrm{ba\color{blue}{cc}ab}&\mathrm{ba\color{blue}{cc}ba}&\mathrm{b\color{blue}{cc}aba}&\mathrm{\color{blue}{cc}abab}&\mathrm{\color{blue}{cc}baba}
> \end{array}
> \end{align*}

**Algebraic derivation:** Formula (3) gives the number of valid sequences with $q$ pairs with runs of length $2$ with $0\leq q\leq n$. Since the number of *all* valid sequences is $\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}$
according to (1), we sum up over $q$ and claim
\begin{align*}
\sum_{q=0}^n\binom{n}{q}\sum_{k=0}^{n-q}(-1)^k\binom{n-q}{k}\frac{(2n-q-k)!}{2^{n-q-k}}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}\qquad n\geq 0\tag{4}
\end{align*}

> We start with the left-hand side of (4) and obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{q=0}^n}&\color{blue}{\binom{n}{q}\sum_{k=0}^{n-q}(-1)^k\binom{n-q}{k}\frac{(2n-q-k)!}{2^{n-q-k}}}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^n\binom{n}{q}\sum_{k=0}^{q}(-1)^k\binom{q}{k}\frac{(n+q-k)!}{2^{q-k}}\tag{4.1}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^n\binom{n}{q}\sum_{k=0}^{q}(-1)^k\binom{q}{k}\frac{(n+k)!}{2^{k}}\tag{4.2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\frac{(n+k)!}{2^k}\sum_{q=k}^n\binom{n}{q}\binom{q}{k}(-1)^q\tag{4.3}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{(n+k)!}{2^k}\sum_{q=k}^n\binom{n-k}{n-q}(-1)^q\tag{4.4}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(n+k)!}{2^k}\sum_{q=0}^{n-k}\binom{n-k}{q}(-1)^q\tag{4.5}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{(n+k)!}{2^k}(1-1)^{n-k}\tag{4.6}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (4.1) we change the order of summation of the outer sum $q\to n-q$.
- In (4.2) we change the order of summation of the inner sum $k\to q-k$.
- In (4.3) we exchange inner and outer sum respecting the index region: $0\leq q\leq k\leq n$.
- In (4.4) we use the binomial identity $\binom{n}{q}\binom{q}{k}=\frac{n!}{(n-q)!}\cdot\frac{1}{k!(q-k)!}=\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{n-q}$.
- In (4.5) we shift the index of the inner sum to start with $q=0$.
- In (4.6) we apply the binomial theorem and observe that all summands with $k<n$ are zero.

Comment: Another wonderful answer / explanation! Thank you so much!

Comment: @DRXhB4m7juFeTZjT: You're welcome! :-)

Comment: For some reason the other question you have answered so brilliantly ( after getting closed ) got deleted now. I have no idea why this happened. I just wanted to be clear about the fact, that it was not I who deleted it.

Comment: @DRXhB4m7juFeTZjT: No worries. The deletion doesn't belong to you. Do you remember the subject of this deleted question?

Comment: Not really, no. I think the title was something like "How to simplify expression". Also, since I went through your answer using pen and paper, I still know how it works! :-). I just feel like it is a shame they would delete such a wonderful answer. I mean, somebody else could also have found it to be useful. Also, why would somebody wanna delete it? I don´t get it.

Comment: @DRXhB4m7juFeTZjT: Since you went through the answer with pen and paper I see you could benefit from the answer and this is what counts. I wouldn't take some decisions regarding deletion of answers too serious. Keep on practicing math and have fun with it. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind and encouraging words! Will do! :-)